# JAXB and XSLT processor

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb

I am using JAXB and maven-jaxb2-plugin and I am able right now to bind my schemas to Java code successfully.
I also have a .xsl file "annotate_schemas.xsl" that modifies a specific schema adding some additional information.
Finally, on the schema that I want transformed, I added the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="annotate_schemas.xsl"?>
...
```

The problem is that, while the .xsl is correct (if I open my schema file in a browser, the transformation is done flawlessly), JAXB ignores it and binds an untouched version of my schema.

My question is: Does JAXB (and/or its plugin) have an XSLT processor?? Is there a way to tell JAXB to bind the result of the XSLT transformation instead of the original?

Thank you very much

Comment: I know I could modify the schema, save it into a new file and run JAXB on that file instead....but I was curious whether a cleaner approach was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB, like the vast majority of XML-consuming applications, takes no notice of an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction. If you want to transform a document before passing it to JAXB, you need to transform it explicitly, for example by using the JAXP transformation API. (There is an option in JAXP to request transformation according to the value of the xml-stylesheet PI if that's how you want to control it: TransformerFactory.useAssociatedStylesheet()).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Templates displayTemplate = transFact.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new File("your_xsl_file")));

TransformerHandler handler = 
  ((SAXTransformerFactory) transFact).newTransformerHandler(displayTemplate);
```

Comment: but this cannot be done at binding time. I need something that would make the transformation BEFORE the maven-jaxb2-plugin starts running....or ideally a way for the pluginitself to perform transformation on-the-fly....